# Why is $\mathbb{Q}/ \mathbb{Z} \otimes \mathbb{Z} /2 \mathbb{Z}$ non-zero?

Tags: modules, tensor-products, tensors

I know that $x \otimes 0 = 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$. So then we have to consider $ \frac{a}{b} \otimes 1 = 2 \frac{a}{2b} \otimes 1 = \frac{a}{2b} \otimes 2 = 0 $

I have been hold this tensor has 2 elements, where have I gone wrong?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with what you did.

Comment: It was specified explicitly in a university mark scheme that many students claimed it was trivial, when in fact it is not

Comment: Well, it is trivial. Actually, $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} A=0$ for any torsion abelian group $A$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your argument looks correct to me. Intuitively, tensoring with $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ annihilates everything divisible by $n$ (via exactly the process you describe but with $2$ replaced by $n$), and in $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ *everything* is divisible by $n$ for each $n$.